# Setting values with if and then & numbers across sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to format a cell in Google Sheets to where if a cell on a different sheet (titled "Additional Options") has a "yes", the cell on the current spreadsheet is 1, but if it says "no", the cell on the current spreadsheet is 0. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is this:

```
=if('Additional Options'!A1="yes",1,0)
```

Assuming your value is in A1 on your target sheet.

Of course, if the value there is anything else, not just "no", it'll return 0. If you want 1 and 0 *only* for "yes" and "no", and something else if it's not one of those values, you can nest your `if` statements.

```
=if('Additional Options'!A1="yes",1,if('Additional Options'!A1="no",0,"-"))
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, it's helpful to "accept" the answer by ticking the checkmark so that it acts as a signpost to future readers.